# Flutter Bloc showes: "Unexpected null value"

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Im trying to develop a Loginscreen in Flutter and im using Bloc(7.3.3) as my Statemanagement. When im loading the screen i get the following error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<LoginBloc?>, MediaQuery], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<LoginBloc, LoginState>#700e3):
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState> BlocBuilder:file:///<PATH>/lib/ui/login/login.dart:73:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 528:63  nullCheck
packages/moena_administration/ui/login/login.dart 130:66                                                                       <fn>
packages/flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart 89:57                                                                              build
packages/flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart 165:21                                                                             build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4705:27                                                                            build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4588:15                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4763:11                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4311:5                                                                             rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4566:5                                                                             [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4754:11                                                                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4561:5                                                                             mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3631:13                                                                            inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3383:18                                                                            updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4613:16                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4763:11                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4311:5                                                                             rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4566:5                                                                             [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4754:11                                                                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4561:5                                                                             mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3631:13                                                                            inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3380:20                                                                            updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4613:16                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4763:11                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4311:5                                                                             rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4795:5                                                                             update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3370:14                                                                            updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4613:16                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4763:11                                                                            performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4311:5                                                                             rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2578:31                                                                            buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 882:9                                                                                drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 363:5                                                                              [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1145:15                                                                            [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1082:9                                                                             handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 863:7                                                                              <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19           internalCallback
====================================================================================================
```

After this error, which is only visible for about half a second, the login screen loads and everything seems to work. I have no idea what this could be. Therefore I have simply times parts of my class and my Bloc attached. Maybe one of you has an idea what is reloading there or how this error can arise.

LoginBloc:

```
part 'login_event.dart';
part 'login_state.dart';

class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  late BasicAuth userRepository;
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginInitial()) {
    userRepository = BasicAuth();
  }
  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(
    LoginEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
      try {
        yield LoginLoading();
        Response response = await userRepository.authenticate(
            password: event.password, username: event.username);
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
          await storage.write(key: 'token', value: response.body['token']);
          BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(event.context)
              .add(LoginSuccessFull());
          yield LoggedIn();
        } else {
          snackBar(context: event.context, message: response.error as String);
          yield LoginFail();
        }
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        snackBar(context: event.context, message: e.toString());
        yield LoginFail();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

LoginScreen:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode _focus = FocusNode();

  rive.Artboard? _riveArtboard;
  rive.StateMachineController? _controller;
  rive.SMIInput<double>? _state;
  rive.SMIInput<double>? _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.load('<File>').then(
      (data) async {
        // Load the RiveFile from the binary data.
        final file = rive.RiveFile.import(data);

        final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        var controller = rive.StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
            artboard, '<Statemachine>');
        if (controller != null) {
          artboard.addController(controller);
          _state = controller.findInput('State');
          _state?.value = 0;
          _loading = controller.findInput('loading');
        }
        setState(() => _riveArtboard = artboard);
      },
    );
    _focus.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focus.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focus.dispose();
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    if (_focus.hasFocus) {
      _state?.value = 1;
    } else {
      _state?.value = 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    '<Filename>',
                    height: 80,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.62,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                        20,
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                        20),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                              blurRadius: 5,
                              spreadRadius: 2)
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 300,
                                    height: 300,
                                    child: rive.Rive(
                                      artboard: _riveArtboard!,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

Thanks very much for helping :)

Comment: packages/moena_administration/ui/login/login.dart 130:66     line number 130 has issue

Comment: Thanks i belive in my first post you can not see this line so i edited the inital post. In that line i use the Animationfile from Rive i imported above: artboard: _riveArtboard!,

Comment: what is rive ? that is null so getting crashed

Comment: You will have to initialise _riveArtboard, its null

Comment: Rive is a tool to animate vector grafics: https://pub.dev/packages/rive. When i start up the App that error only appeares a short time and then the hole side with the animation loads correctly so i belive i need to delay something for the rive plugin to load the file, could that be the case?

Comment: added solution in answers pls check

Comment: As you can see above in intilise _riveArtboard in initState() but thats async so i belive it takes to long, but im not shure how to wait on this

Comment: right, but instead of using null value, show blank space or a loader

Comment: use the answer I added that would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is crashing because _riveArtboard is being accessed before it is getting initialised. To fix this use following code null check :

```
         Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                  Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    child: rive.Rive(
                      artboard: _riveArtboard!,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

or show progressIndicator :

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    child: _riveArtboard != null
                        ? rive.Rive(
                            artboard: _riveArtboard!,
                          )
                    : ProgressIndicator(width:30,height:30),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Showing a LoadingIndicator worked perfectly thank you very much